# How to restrict user to view directory If subDomain Url format is wrong

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Currently, I am redirecting all my subdomains to a particular folder using the .htaccess file. Below I have mentioned my .htaccess file code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirection of subDomain to v1 subdirectory
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.abc\.com$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /v1/$1 [END,NE,R=permanent]
</IfModule>
```

Problem is If anyone enters wrong subdomain url like 123.122.abc.com, then this also redirects to /v1 directory. I want only one level subdomains.

Comment: This should probably be asked on https://serverfault.com/.

Comment: That matching pattern you posted will _not_ accept `123.122.abc.com`. You will have to check deeper what is wrong with your setup, it is _not_ that matching pattern. My first guess: you are looking at client side cached results from earlier attempts with a different matching pattern. Remember: always test your setup using a fresh anonymous browser window. Also taking a look into your browser's console, the network tab in there, is helpful to understand what response you actually receive from server or local cache.

Comment: And (as I mentioned in your [dupe/question on ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/1142933/how-to-restrict-user-to-view-directory-if-subdomain-url-format-is-wrong)) this rule (by itself) would otherwise result in a redirect-loop for single-level subdomains. So, you must have other directives/config that prevents this, or this `.htaccess` is not actually doing anything at all??